# Progressbar values from loop on other form?

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I wold like to create a progressbar for my application, im running i got one main form that opens a Child form with a datagrid with a loop i<30. the loop takes a bit of time as it querys the database.

this hold up looks to the user like the software is stuck, so i was thinking of creating a progressbar to show how long the operation is in the loop.

what is needed how do i start solving this problem?

form1 = Main form
Child1 = datagrid form
Child2 = Progressbar form

i was thinking on letting the main form hold a int variable poX = 0
and the child1 do in the loop

```
for (int i, i < 30, i++)
{
   //code for query
   form1.posX = form1.posX++
}
```

then let Child2 use the poX to progress the bar.
But is this the correct path? and how do i pass values from the children to the main form and back?

Comment: {form1.posX = form1.posX++} won't work. Use {form1.posX++} alone or {form1.posX = form1.posX + 1}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use a different thread to perform your lengthy operation while updating the progress bar. This wont freeze your UI thread. Take a look into [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class and [How To Use BackgroundWorker](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx)